# Can you echo F-Keys through a Pipe to another program?

Tags: bash, pipe, stdin

I am trying to write a short bash hack that requires piping keystrokes of the F-Keys
basically what I am trying to do is:

```
(echo "1"; "for x in 1..9; do echo "123<F1>34<F3>"; done; echo "<F1>")|./program
```

where  is the F-key with that #

is this possible? if so can some one point me to the docs, or something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your terminal, a function-key is just a sequence of characters. You can see what they are with `cat`:

```
$ cat
^[OP
^[OQ
^[OR
```

This is me hitting <kbd>F1</kbd>, <kbd>F2</kbd>, <kbd>F3</kbd> in sequence. So to echo them into your program, you can just echo those control codes (note the first one there is <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>ESC</kbd>), and you should be all set.

Comment: Thanks, after I read that I almost banged my head on my desk. After 10 years of using Linux I should have known that... But on the bright side the answer is out there for other people!

Answer (score 0):

To expand on zigdon's answer, you can use `tput` to produce the right sequences for your terminal:

```
f1=$(tput kf1)
f2=$(tput kf2)
# ...
(echo 1; for x in {1..9}; do echo "123${f1}34$f3"; done; echo "$f1") | ./program
```

The "kf1" and "kf2" names are the [terminfo capabilities](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?terminfo+5) for the F1 and F2 keys, respectively.